# Shortcut to Clear History and Website Data

Tags: ios, automation, privacy, mobile-safari, shortcuts-app

Clear History and Website Data for Safari is deeply hidden in Settings. Tap, tap, tap.

With the new Shortcuts App in iOS 13 can I create a shortcut to clear history?